# How to rename to command output?

Tags: bash, mv

Let's say I have a file `abc.pdf`

I want to rename it to `Endesa` + the output of this command:

```
pdftotext -raw abc.pdf - | grep 'Periodo de consumo' | sed -E 's_.*: ([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4}) a ([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})_\3-\2-\1 \6-\5-\4_g'
```

I.e., `Endesa 2016-07-12 2016-08-09.pdf`

Can I do this with a one-liner, without having to type the name of the file twice?

I tried

```
mv abd.pdf < "Endesa "$(pdftotext....)
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just use execute the command with `$()` without any need to use process substitution. This will be executed in a way that the output of the command will be placed just after `"Endesa"`:

```
mv abc.pdf "Endesa""$(your command)"
```

For example I just created a file `Endesa1471530429.pdf` in my computer by running `touch "Endesa"$(date "+%s")".pdf"`.

Since the parameter of `pdftotext` is the file itself you can save some time by storing the value in a variable and using it twice:

```
mv "$your_file" "Endesa""$(pdftotext -raw "$your_file" - | grep ...)"
```

Comment: Ah, OK! So `f=abc; mv $f.pdf  "Endesa $(pdftotext -raw $f.pdf - ...).pdf"` — **it works!**

Comment: @Ze'ev yep! Although it is good to get used to quote things, so say `mv "$f" ...`, just in case the name contains some spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Simple as:

```
mv abd.pdf "Endesa $(pdftotext....)"
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this; using a variable

```
NEWNAME=$(pdftotext....) ; mv abc.pdf "Endesa $NEWNAME"
```